# Display In an html table key pair values. The key should be a header

Tags: php

I have the following array in php:

```
$values=[
          [
            ['key'=>"Name",'value'=>"John"],
            ['key'=>'Surname','value'=>"Doe"],
            ['key'=>"email",'value'=>'john@doe.com']
          ],
          [
            ['key'=>"Surname",'value'=>"Ichigo"], 
            ['key'=>'Name','value'=>"Kurosaki"],
            ['key'=>'email','value'=>'kurosakiighogo@soulsociety.com']
          ],
          [
            ['key'=>"email",'value'=>"monket.d@luffy.com"],
            ['key'=>'Name','value'=>"Monkey D."],
            ['key'=>'Surame','value'=>'Luffy']
          ],
        ];
```

And I want somehow to be generated as:

```
$values2=[
         head=>['Name','Surname','email'],
         values=>[
                   ["John","Doe","john@doe.com"],
                   ["Kurosaki","Ichigo","kurosakiighogo@soulsociety.com"],
                   ['Monkey D.','Luffy','monket.d@luffy.com']
                 ]
        ]
```

The key point I want is on head to be stored the keys and on values the values. But with the same Order.

To be specific on values[$i][$j] I want to be stored the $values['value'] where $values['key'] === head[j].

The problem is NOT HOW TO DISPLAY the array $values2 but HOW TO TRANSFORM $values array into $values2.

Comment: Code you tried so far;

Comment: Actually I have no Idea how to syncronize the head with the values.

Comment: How you stored data in `$values`?

Comment: It is the way Is presented on $values. In my read problem the $values is a result from a EXTREMELY complex query.

Comment: You want to show this data in table 2nd array right? And you don't know how to loop array?

Comment: Yes. I want to be avle to show them in any table - like structure either html table or Excell - generated table.

Comment: I would start by looking at the query that generates this data and making that produce a better structure. If the data is unusable as it is then fix what creates the unusable data!

Comment: Ii is not possible because there are many other parameters and the data from the query depending the curcumstances need to be transformed and sanitized.

Comment: Of course its possible, Show us the query and someone will make it produce usable data

Comment: I cannot do that. My boss will go mad.

Comment: You want to create array from `$values` to be like `$values2`?

Comment: Ok, so show us the table layout that you want, I dont see why you cannot use `$values` to produce a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
$values = [
  [
    ['key'=>"Name",
      'value'=>"John"],
    ['key'=>'Surname',
      'value'=>"Doe"],
    ['key'=>"email",
      'value'=>'john@doe.com']
  ],
  [
    ['key'=>"Surname",
      'value'=>"Ichigo"],
    ['key'=>'Name',
      'value'=>"Kurosaki"],
    ['key'=>'email',
      'value'=>'kurosakiighogo@soulsociety.com']
  ],
  [
    ['key'=>"email",
      'value'=>"monket.d@luffy.com"],
    ['key'=>'Name',
      'value'=>"Monkey D."],
    ['key'=>'Surname',
      'value'=>'Luffy']
  ],
];

$records = [];
$keyIndex = [];
foreach($values as $index=> $record){
  $thisRecord = [];
  foreach($record as $index1=> $field){
    if(!$index){
      $keyIndex[$field['key']] = $index1;
      $records['head'][] = $field['key'];
    }
    $thisRecord[$keyIndex[$field['key']]] = $field['value'];
  }
  ksort($thisRecord);
  $records['values'][] = $thisRecord;
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the point of the question. The `$value2` array **does not exist** he wants to create the `$value2` array from the `$values` array which does exist.

Comment: @RiggsFolly is this fine?

Comment: I guess. But I would not assume that you can just hard code the `'head'` I bet he wants that built dynamically as well. I would imagine his example has been simplified from the real array

Comment: Also note: He has changed the layout of his `$values` array. Everything is now `key=>value` even the `'email'`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i think now it's fine.

Comment: Well so does the guy asking the question. +1 for perseverance

Comment: @itzmukeshy7  reviewed your answer because I found a small bug that I fixed it. Thanks for your time!